# How do I specify an outcome variable (y) as count data using a poisson regression in a multilevel model?

Tags: interaction, multilevel-analysis, count-data

I have three variables with multilevel data:
Level 1 DV: deviant behaviour
Level 1 IV: negative affect
Level 2 IV: consideration of others (personality trait)

Here is my model:

```
Model.CWBI <- lme(CWBI. ~ SBIcnt. + AGRCNT. + SBIcnt. : AGRCNT.,
                  random = ~SBIcnt. | partid., data=Bored, na.action = na.omit)
```

How do I take into account the fact that my DV is count data?

Answer (score 2):

If your data is indeed count data, you should run a GLMM (Generalized linear mixed-effects model) instead. This can be done using `glmer()` function from the `lme4` package and specifying `family = poisson` to model the counts. There is a lot of information here on Cross Validated on those models and also on the [glmmFAQ site](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html).